# Plotting and removing a vertical line inside a loop matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas DataFrame `stock_open` that contains stock prices vs dates and looks like:
[image: Stock prices vs dates]

I want to plot the time series line-plot of stock prices versus the date column and show the dates increasing by plotting a vertical line for each date. I want to achieve this by plotting the graphs for a few dates, saving those plots as separate images and then use ffmpeg to combine them into a video. So, I did this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

my_dates = ['2019-11-20', '2019-12-20', '2020-01-20', '2020-02-20', '2020-03-20']

fig, [[ax1, ax2], [ax3, ax4]] = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(20, 8))

sns.lineplot(x='Date', y='value', hue='variable',
             data=pd.melt(stock_open, ['Date']), ax=ax3)
ax3.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plot_no = 0
for i in range(len(my_dates)):
    my_selected_date = my_dates[i]
    ax3.axvline(my_selected_date)
    ax3.set_title(str(my_selected_date))
    fig.savefig('output_images/stock_image_{plot_no:04d}.png'.format(plot_no=plot_no))
    plot_no += 1
```

Everything is working fine except that the vertical line 'persists' in the figures in all the iterations.

The first image is as expected:
[image: stock_plot_0000]

But the images from the following iterations in the loop have the vertical line from the previous iteration:
[image: stock_plot_0004]

(images are cropped intentionally)

I want to remove the vertical line from the previous iterations.

I thought of using animations from matplotlib, but the other subfigures also need to be updated and saved in this process.

Is there a way to do this without starting from the beginning?
Initially I wanted to show a moving line-plot with the date, but couldn't achieve that either. So I used this strategy to show updates on the figure.

TIA!

Comment: capture the output of `ax.axvline` and then use the `set_xdata`(?) method on it to move it

Comment: @PaulH Thanks for the answer! This may be very basic, but could you explain how to capture the output of `ax3.axvline()` inside the loop? Is there a function to do that? Could you point me towards some exaples? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWERED!

[Original answer from @YesLod on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/g8hsz3/plotting_and_removing_a_vertical_line_inside_a/fonxvcg?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

```
for i in range(len(my_dates)):
    my_selected_date = my_dates[i]
    line=ax3.axvline(my_selected_date)   # changed
    ax3.set_title(str(my_selected_date))
    fig.savefig('output_images/stock_image_{plot_no:04d}.png'.format(plot_no=plot_no))
    plot_no += 1

    plt.pause(0.1)  # added
    line.remove()   # added
```

Thanks!